# In two step authentication, should I check step 1 before proceeding to step 2 or check both at the end?

Tags: security, forms-authentication

I have a typical web application forms authentication process with two steps:

- Step 1: Request username and password
- Step 2: Request some characters from a secret phrase

Should I authenticate the username and password before going to Step 2? Or should I collect all three bits of information (username, password and characters) and check them at the end?

Most websites I've seen check the username and password and if they don't authenticate, never ask for the characters. On the other hand, it could be argued that checking everything at the end and if they don't match, displaying an error message that doesn't explain which bit failed would be more secure. That gives away less information like displaying "Username or password is incorrect" (without specifying which) in a simple 1 step authentication.

The problem with the second approach (aside from being less user-friendly) is that Step 2 requires obtaining a valid user in Step 1, otherwise it's hard to know the length of the secret phrase to ask for valid characters (there's no point asking for the 10th character if the phrase is only 9 characters long). The application would also have to hold on to the password in a secure manner between the two steps.

So which one is better? Is there a third approach I should consider?

Comment: On step 2 you should not give a length hint as this leaks information as well. Let the user enter whatever he wants.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Step 2 needs to ask for characters that actually exist in the secret phrase. Am I missing something?

Comment: "there's no point in asking 10th character" - by not asking it you tell the attacker, that the phrase consists of just 9 characters. This is a leak of information, which should not occur.

Comment: Yes, I get that but what's the alternative?

Comment: Ask the user for everything, then compare everything. Remember about timing attacks as well (this can be prevented by limiting the number of failed attempts for user account to some reasonable value). You will get more suggestions on http://security.stackexchange.com/